# Parse two files and merge lines if time-stamp matches

Tags: bash, sed, awk, tcl

I have two data files of the following format:

File1:

```
date,time,data1,data2,data3
date,time,data1,data2,data3
date,time,data1,data2,data3
```

File2:

```
date,time,data4
date,time,data4
```

What I want to do is to merge the lines in these two files in such a way that if date and time match then the output should be:

```
date,time,data1,data2,data3,data4
```

In case the the time-stamp from one file does not match anything in the other file then I can ignore that line.

I'm currently doing this using a combination of awk and join. But I wonder if this is the most effective way to do this or not.

Current working implementation is something like this:

```
 awk 'FS="," {print $1"&"$2 ","$3","$4","$5}' File1 > temp1
 awk 'FS="," {print $1"&"$2 ","$3}' File2 > temp2
 join -t',' -j1 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 temp1 temp2 > temp3
 awk 'FS="&" {print $1","$2"}' temp3 > Output
```

Comment: I think if you do not post what you've tried so far, the question will probably get closed.

Comment: Questions asking to **recommend** or find **a tool**, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Sorry for not being more details in the question. I was able to do what the problem statement demanded using a combination of awk and join. I'll update the question with my answer - and re-phrase the question.

Comment: You don't need `join` if you're already using awk. If you want help, post some actual representative sample input and expected output, not just the placeholder word `date` repeated N times in each file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd do this (assuming that the dates and times have a *precisely* matching format) would be:

```
proc tidyUpTimestamp {date time} {
    # If you want to parse/tidy up the timestamp, do so here
    return $date,$time
}

# Schlurp the data into an array for ease of access. Good for a few million lines
set f [open "file2.csv"]
foreach line [split [read $f] "\n"] {
    lassign [split $line ","] date time data4
    set map([tidyUpTimestamp $date $time]) $data4
}
close $f

# Assuming that file1.csv is much longer than file2.csv
set fin [open "file1.csv"]
set fout [open "file1.processed.csv" w]
while {[gets $fin line] >= 0} {
    lassign [split $line ","] date time;   # Ignore other fields...
    set ts [tidyUpTimestamp $date $time]
    if {[info exist map($ts)]} {
        # Simple concatenation!
        puts $fout "$line,$map($ts)"
    }
}
close $fout
close $fin
```

If the dates and times are not precisely equal, you'll need to do some cleaning up as the above code works entirely on the *textual* representation of everything. Just pop that into the `tidyUpTimestamp` procedure…

Answer (score 2):

A flexible and general way of manipulating data is python pandas. Worth mentioning here as it really is the right tool for the job. Allows spreadsheet or database style merges/joins/concats on selected index rows or columns.

Two example files to illustrate how it works

```
$ cat File1
date0,time0,data01,data02,data03
date1,time1,data11,data12,data13
date2,time2,data21,data22,data23
date3,time3,data31,data32,data33
date4,time4,data41,data42,data43
date5,time5,data51,data52,data53
$ cat File2
date1,time1,data14
date4,time4,data44
date2,time2,data24
```

Run python . . .

- Use pandas read_csv to slurp in files in pandas table structure.
  (read_csv is very clever and can read in many formats not just csv)
- Use pandas merge to do inner(intersection of indices) join,
  using date+time as indices (index list=[0,1]).
- Use pandas to_csv to write output.

**THE IMPORTANT BIT:**

```
$ python
>>> from pandas import merge, read_csv
>>> f1=read_csv("File1",header=None)
>>> f2=read_csv("File2",header=None)
>>> merged = merge(f1, f2, how='inner', left_on=[0,1], right_on=[0,1])
>>> merged.to_csv("Out", na_rep=0, index=False, header=False)
>>> [Ctrl-D]
```

**Job done!**

```
$ cat Out
date1,time1,data11,data12,data13,data14
date2,time2,data21,data22,data23,data24
date4,time4,data41,data42,data43,data44
```

VERY clean, no messing. I really do love bash/grep/sed/awk also perl and python manipulating data in structures BUT right tool for the job makes the job much easier and gives much more potential for use of the data.

**Breakdown:**

**1. read_csv** A bog-standard(plain, unadorned) **'read_csv("File1")'** treats first line as header names. So we use 'header=None'.

```
>>> f1=read_csv("File1")
>>> f1
date0  time0  data01  data02  data03
0  date1  time1  data11  data12  data13
1  date2  time2  data21  data22  data23
2  date3  time3  data31  data32  data33
3  date4  time4  data41  data42  data43
4  date5  time5  data51  data52  data53
>>> f1=read_csv("File1",header=None)
>>> f1
0      1       2       3       4
0  date0  time0  data01  data02  data03
1  date1  time1  data11  data12  data13
2  date2  time2  data21  data22  data23
3  date3  time3  data31  data32  data33
4  date4  time4  data41  data42  data43
5  date5  time5  data51  data52  data53
>>> f2=read_csv("File2",header=None)
```

**pandas DataFrame 'describe()'** gives a useful summary especially for big tables. For numeric data you also get total, max, min, mean, e.t.c.

```
>>> f1.describe()
0      1       2       3       4
count       6      6       6       6       6
unique      6      6       6       6       6
top     date4  time3  data01  data12  data13
freq        1      1       1       1       1
```

**2. merge**

**how** specifies left/right/inner/outer merge style sql join terminology. **how='left'** takes first file indices (date+time) as output and merge in the second files data. **how='right'** takes the second files indices as output and merge in the first files data. **how='inner'** does an intersection between each files indices (date+time) so only data for which you have entries in both files are taken. **how='outer'** does an union between each files indices (date+time) so all data is written, data for which you do not have entries in both files is filled with 'NaN' values.

**on/left_on/right_on index select** We could also use **'on=[0,1]'** as our input files have the same columns of indices (and they are named the same 0 and 1 as we read in the file with 'header=None').

```
>>> merged = merge(f1, f2, how='inner', left_on=[0,1], right_on=[0,1])
>>> merged
0      1     2_x       3       4     2_y
0  date1  time1  data11  data12  data13  data14
1  date2  time2  data21  data22  data23  data24
2  date4  time4  data41  data42  data43  data44
>>> mergedOut = merge(f1, f2, how='outer', left_on=[0,1], right_on=[0,1])
>>> mergedOut
0      1     2_x       3       4     2_y
0  date0  time0  data01  data02  data03     NaN
1  date1  time1  data11  data12  data13  data14
2  date2  time2  data21  data22  data23  data24
3  date3  time3  data31  data32  data33     NaN
4  date4  time4  data41  data42  data43  data44
5  date5  time5  data51  data52  data53     NaN
```

**3. to_csv** we write out without and index or a header using 'index=False' and 'header=False'. See the output with index and header written to the "Out2" file:

```
>>> merged.to_csv("Out2")
>>> merged.to_csv("Out", na_rep=0, index=False, header=False)

$ cat Out2
,0,1,2_x,3,4,2_y
0,date1,time1,data11,data12,data13,data14
1,date2,time2,data21,data22,data23,data24
2,date4,time4,data41,data42,data43,data44
$ cat Out
date1,time1,data11,data12,data13,data14
date2,time2,data21,data22,data23,data24
date4,time4,data41,data42,data43,data44
```

Documentation to get started with:

- pandas IO tools for reading and writing data files:
  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html
- the pandas DataFrame objects:
  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html
  Select rows/columns/data. Operate on part or all of dataset. Loads of stuff.
- pandas merging/join/concat
  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

To get pandas and install: http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html

```
# download, unpack and:
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the files, separately, don't have duplicates of `date,time` I would `cat` them together, `sort` and in `awk` if current line has the same `date,time` as previous one then print previous line and append data from current line:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt | \
    sort | \
    awk '
function getOnlyData()
{
    onlyData="";
    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++)
    {
        onlyData = onlyData "," $i;
    }
    return onlyData
}
BEGIN {
    FS=",";
}
{
    if (prevDate==$1 && prevTime==$2)
    {
        currData = getOnlyData()
        print $1 "," $2 prevData currData
    }
    prevDate=$1;
    prevTime=$2;
    prevData=getOnlyData();
}'
```

For input:

> ```
> 2013-10-07,12:00:00,a1,b1,c1
> 2013-10-07,13:00:00,a2,b2,c2
> 2013-10-07,14:00:00,a3,b3,c3
> 2013-10-07,15:00:00,x4,y4,z4
> 2013-10-07,16:00:00,x5,y5,z5
> ```

and

> ```
> 2000-10-07,12:00:00,d1
> 2013-10-07,13:00:00,d2
> 2000-10-07,14:00:00,d3
> 2013-10-07,15:00:00,d4
> 2000-10-07,16:00:00,d5
> ```

the output is:

> ```
> 2013-10-07,13:00:00,a2,b2,c2,d2
> 2013-10-07,15:00:00,d4,x4,y4,z4
> ```